# Linux Script to check for SetUID

Tags: linux, if-statement, setuid

I need to write a script file to check for SetUID programs with the permission of 4755. How can I do this?

Comment: Writing code would be a good start. We are not here to do your job for you. tip: `man find`

Answer (score 1):

In bash:

```
path=/pathtosearch
find $path -perm 4755
```

Comment: You should check *any* SUID file, not just ones with that *exact* mode.